# ¿Por que mi variable de tipo decimal solo guarda valores enteros?

Tags: c#

tengo un problema con este fragmento de codigo:

```
public decimal consumo_promedio(int serial_mic)
    {

        foreach (var item in objconnection.consumo_lco(serial_mic))
        {
            a = a + item.consumo_lco;
            counter++;
        }

        decimal promedio = (a / counter);

      decimal aux = Math.Round(promedio,MidpointRounding.ToEven);

        return aux;
    }
```

basicamente lo que quiero es que la variable promedio realize una operacion basica, la cual es dividir 29/6 por ejemplo...las variables a y counter son enteros pero se supone que dependiendo de los casos la variable promedio puede o no obtener valores decimales....el problema esta en que la variable promedio solo me almacena la parte entera del resultado y no la parte decimal...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

El resultado de la división de un `int` por otro `int` te va a dar un `int`.
Una forma de resolver esto es castear uno de los operadores a `decimal`. Entonces el resultado va a ser un `decimal`

```
int x = 10;
int y = 3;
var z = x / (decimal)y;
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Esto imprimie 3.33 (periódico)

Ver: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fGvoiN

Comment: Gracias #harkcoded ya habia solucionado justo de la forma en la que sugerias....thanks by the way...}

Answer (score -1):

Es por la fución de [Math.Round();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx). Con un parámetro retorna solo la parte entera. Agregando el segundo parámetro te lo da en decimales solicitades.

```
decimal aux = Math.Round(promedio,MidpointRounding.ToEven, 2);
```

Comment: entiendo tu punto pero el problema es que a esa instancia de codigo la variable 'promedio' ya ha llegado sin ningun  decimal, so, la funcion Math.Round hara su trabajo pero no encontrara nada para redondear...gracias por tu ayuda...ya lo he solucionado casteando uno de los valores a decimal...